# Doctrine2 criteria filtering can't find property

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm filtering an entity in Symfony2 that has an association with a "start_date" property. This is the value in the DB and it has a Doctrine-generated getter of getStartDate. Inside the filter method, I use an expression of

```
Criteria::expr()->gt('start_date', $now)
```

but that fails with an error about accessing a protected property. If I change the criteria to

```
Criteria::expr()->gt('startDate', $now)
```

it fails again but this time with an error about not having that property on the object. Which is correct? I shouldn't need to add a separate getting for just the criteria filtering.

Comment: Please show how `start_date` is defined in your Entity and in your database schema.

Comment: `/**
* @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
*/
protected $start_date;` and `public function getStartDate()`

Comment: Errors are "Error: Cannot access protected property" for start_date and "Unrecognized field: startDate" for startDate

Answer (score 2):

Correct is first case:

```
Criteria::expr()->gt('start_date', $now)
```

Is getter public? Try to make this property public. Is error still display in this case?

Also try to add next getters for test:

```
public function start_date(){};

public function getStart_date(){};
```

**You must to correct your code to this**:

```
/** 
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", name="start_date") 
 */

protected $startDate; 

public function getStartDate() {

    return $this->startDate;
}
```

and then use:

```
Criteria::expr()->gt('startDate', $now)
```

Symfony need to call your proprties in camelCase style, then camelCase getters will be work

Comment: Thank you, Victor, adding getStart_date seems to have it, but I don't understand why Doctrine doesn't understand the standard property getters?

Comment: Maybe you found a bug )

Comment: Do you use last version of Doctrine? And do you use Symfony with Doctrine?

Comment: I'm using Symfony2 with Doctrine and I just ran composer's update function so I believe doctrine is fully updated.

Comment: Named your property `protected $startDate;` and it's work, check answer